# Exam pseudocode recursive function

Tags: pseudocode

I have this exam question:

Look at this example of pseudocode:

```
algorithm A(a, b) {
    // precond: a & b are type of Int
    // postcond: what does this function return?
    if (a == b)
        return( 0 )
    else if (a < b)
        return (-A(b, a))
    else
        return (A(a-1, b-1));
}
```

The answers given are:

- a) a-b
- b) a+b
- c) max(a,b)
- d) Will loop infinitely

Personally I think it's d), but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Try it on your computer.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in Flash (AS3.0), and my program crashed when I set (1,2) or (2,1), but I'm not sure if it's just Flashs fault.
And sorry if this example seems stupid. My girlfriend had it on her exam, and most people thought that there's a mistake in this question.

Answer (score 1):

The function terminates when `a==b`; so to show that it *doesn't* terminate, you could show that a & b never get closer together with successive calls -- which in this case, is pretty easy.

(The above does not take into account overflow.  Also, (d) can't be correct, since it doesn't *loop* at all.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that there is no loop :) answer d) should be something like: it results in infinite recursion

Answer (score 1):

As long as a and b are not equal,

If a is less than b, the next function call would make a>b. 
(For example calling A(3,4) would return -A(4,3) )

Subsequently, the function calls would result in an infinite recursion, as it keeps returning A(a-1, b-1) without termination.
(For example calling A(4,3) would return A(3,2) which would return A(2,1) and so on)

Answer (score -1):

The only value the function will return is 0. And that's when a == b. But then, 0 = a - b for all (a,b) so that a == b. So I think the right answer is a).